# Which model to choose with an unsupervised anomaly detection problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, signals, anomaly-detection

I have an anomaly detection problem with a lot of signal data (1700, 64 100) il the length of the dataframe.
The problem is that I am a beginner in anomaly detection and  there is NO anomalies in the training set. (Of course there are some in the validation set).

I tried to use KNN and isolation forest with the pyod library, but there is a "contamination" parameter that needs to be superior to 0. But in my case there isn't anomalies as previously said.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contamination defines your expectation of the percentage of data being outliers. If there is no outliers, why would you like to detect them?

I would say the better approach will be using the entire dataset for building the model instead of train/test split :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To be clearer i have one dataframe (train) filled with inliers. I have an unlabelled test df with some anomalies (for a competition).

Comment: @Jinter I think that is novelty detection, which slightly different from anomaly detection. From a practical side, I think you could combine the exisiting data and the unseen data together to make a prediction. Another way is still use anomaly detection and predict on new samples for their scores (use decision_function). After you get the score of the unseen data, you could set up a threshold for outliers, e.g., scores>0.3. Do not worry about the contamination parameter, it is only used in binary label prediction but not decision_function.